# Get number of duplicates between any amount of rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

**EDIT** (Updated following solutions suggested)

I need to count the number of duplicates between two rows (in one formula) :

```
Row 1>  20  21  22  41    
Row 2>  3   20  30  22  47  49
```

Here the result should be 2 (20 & 22)

The two following formulas are working :

```
=COUNT(FILTER(UNIQUE(flatten(TRANSPOSE(A2:F3))), ARRAYFORMULA( COUNTIF(flatten(TRANSPOSE(A2:F3)),UNIQUE(flatten(TRANSPOSE(A2:F3))))>1 )))
```

and

```
=countif(query(flatten(A2:F), "Select count(Col1) group by Col1"), ">1")
```

But as soon as the two rows are not in the same sheet the formula doesn't work anymore (even with bracket)

Here is a Google Sheet with sample data and result : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PRNGgzAmpQUE0nCCuxBPJbM4gESUtnSMQf-cXG3ozBo/edit?usp=sharing

What do you think ?

Thank you !

Comment: Your `COUNTIF` probably didn't work because you'd need to transpose those values first, e.g.: `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(1:1,TRANSPOSE(2:2)))`. Also, since it's an array formula you'd either need `ARRAYFORMULA` or `SUMPRODUCT`. Also, if an answer below suited your needs, consider to upvote/accept it as such. Off-topic, you might want to revisit most of your former questions and see if there are answers for you to accept and therefor close those questions.

Comment: Thank you I updated the question

Comment: The formula you try in your edited question will never work for different sheets. You **must use curly brackets** as in `=COUNT(FILTER(UNIQUE(flatten({A2:F2;Sheet1!A22:F22})), ARRAYFORMULA( COUNTIF(flatten({A2:F2;Sheet1!A22:F22}),UNIQUE(flatten({A2:F2;Sheet1!A22:F22})))>1 )))`

Comment: Have you even tried my suggestion?

Comment: The reason it does NOT work is because in one sheet you have numbers and in the other one you have text as numbers. :)

Comment: Sorry JvdV I didn't test ! I can see it works great !!

Comment: Oh so right marikamitsos !!! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** *(following OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62890270/get-number-of-duplicates-between-two-rows#comment111215471_62890980))*

Please use the following formula **without** a helper column

```
=COUNT(FILTER(UNIQUE(flatten(TRANSPOSE(A2:F3))), ARRAYFORMULA( COUNTIF(flatten(TRANSPOSE(A2:F3)),UNIQUE(flatten(TRANSPOSE(A2:F3))))>1 )))
```

---

*Original reply*

You can use the following two formulas

For the "helper" column

```
=flatten(TRANSPOSE(A2:F3))
```

For the count:

```
=COUNTIF(ArrayFormula(if(H2:H="","",countifs(H2:H,H2:H,row(H2:H),"<="&row(H2:H)))),">1")
```

[image]

You can also incorporate them in a single formula by replacing `H2:H` with `flatten(TRANSPOSE(A2:F3))` in the second formula

Comment: Wow great idea ! With the helper column it works perfectly. But if I try to replace H2:H with the flatten formula it doesn't work anymore. Too bad since I would like to do it in a single cell (I have a lot of rows ...). Thank you !

Comment: Please check the edited answer. I would also recomment changing the title from "two rows" to "any amount of rows"

Comment: Thank you ! I updated the title. Other question, if the second row is in another sheet, how can I use the same formula ?

Comment: Just replace the formula range with `flatten({A2:F2;Sheet1!A22:F22})`

Comment: Strange. Works in my end. Please share a test sheet.

Comment: Just update the main post with a link to a Google Sheet. You can edit to play with it :) Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Using a different approach,

```
=countif(query(flatten(A2:F), "Select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), ">1")
```

or even

```
=countif(query(flatten(A2:F), "Select count(Col1) group by Col1"), ">1")
```

EDIT: Since one of the rows is formatted as text you'll have to convert to number

```
=ArrayFormula(countif(query(flatten({value(B4:U4);Sheet1!B2:U2}), "Select count(Col1) group by Col1"), ">1"))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice and economical, JPV.

Comment: Nice one ! Thank you. Other question, if the second row is in another sheet, how can I use the same formula ?

Comment: Construct an array literal : =countif(query(flatten({A2:F2; Sheet2!A3:F3}), "Select count(Col1) group by Col1"), ">1")

Comment: Maybe it would be best to share a copy of your spreadsheet  and show us what you try to achieve. That way we can see how your data is structured and look for a solution.

Comment: Seems like one of the rows were text. I updated the formula.